# Shouldn't the OP be notified if his/her question is put on hold or closed or edited?

Tags: feature-request, editing, closed-questions

I recently asked a question which was put on hold. I was not notified of it being put on hold. I was always notified if my question had any answer or comment. If I had received the notification, I had edited the question early.

Comment: This has been discussed many times at meta.SE; the "main" thread is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842). Please note that, ultimately, there is no way we can implement such a feature by ourselves. As a workaround you may be interested in the userscript [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/6384/question-close-notifier-a-userscript-to-notify-you-when-one-of-your-questions) (I don't know if it works).

Comment: Plus, you do get notifications for edits on your questions. There's some fine detail, such as a minimal edit not pinging or similar, but I don't remember it now. You also get notified if someone suggests an edit on your question.